# Suggestions for creating high-fidelity UI mockups that can be inserted and edited from MS Word?

Tags: user-interface, design

We use MS Word for software specs. These specs contain UI mockups.

This is what the company uses to access these specs, so gotta stick with MS Word.

Looking for something to easily design high-fidelity UI's but then put them into MS Word *and* be able to just click on them to open the tool they were edited in.

**Background**

Seems like we could *either* use the built in MS Word editing tools to design UI (hard to make it pixel-accurate) OR use a 3rd party tool but then when you wanna make a change, you have to go find the source document.

**One solution** would be to insert the UI as an editable elements. So ideally, you edit it in, say, Basalmiq, and then insert into Word. Click the inserted "object" and open Basalmiq.

Does not need to be a free solution (althought that's easier to get approved). MS office is a plus.